# Which questions are tweeted on @StackAndroid?

Tags: discussion, twitter

Who decides, which questions are getting tweeted on [@StackAndroid](https://twitter.com/#!/StackAndroid) feed?
 Or, if it is automated process, what are the conditions and which questions are chosen?

Comment: It's automatic.  If I recall it's "the most popular active question that hasn't been tweeted before" once every 3 hours, or something along those lines.  Someone from SE would have to provide more detail.

Comment: What Matt said, it's an automatic thing. The @ AndroidSE that I originally created before @ StackAndroid came about just pulled directly from the RSS feed

Answer (score 3):

This is completely automated - as described [on Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/101340#101340), a scheduled process will tweet: blog posts, chat events, questions and answers meeting certain criteria and meta questions meeting certain criteria.

Comment: However, they [*are* running experiments to kill the Twitter robot](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4137/killing-the-robot-in-our-twitter-account).